# Isolate reactivity in an ordered list

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming

I have got a template that shows tiles in a particular order:

```
<template name="container">
{{#each tiles}}{{>tile}}{{/each}}
</template>
```

Now the container is a list of tiles that is stored as an array in mongodb.

Since I want the tiles to be shown in the same order as they appear in that array, I'm using the following helper:

```
Template.container.tiles = function () {
        return _.map(this.tiles || [], function(tileId) {
              return _.extend({
                   container: this
              }, Tiles.findOne({_id: tileId}));
        }, this);
    };
};
```

The problem is, that I:

- Do not want the entire container to rerender when the any of it's contain tiles changes. (Only the relevent tile should be invalidated).
- Do not want the entire container to rerender when a new tile is inserted. The rendered tile should be simply appended or insteted at the respective location.
- Do not want the entire container to rerender when the order of the tiles is changed. Instead, when the order changes, the DOM objects that represent the tile should be rearranged without re-rendering the tile itself.

With the above approach I will not meet the requirements, because the each tiles data is marked as a dependency (when running `Tiles.findOne({_id: tileId})`) of the entire container and the entire array of tile-ids is part of the containers data and if that changes the entire container template is invalidated.

I'm thinking I should mark the cursor for the container as non-reactive. Something like this:

```
Containers.findOne({_id: containerId}, {reactive:false});
```

But I still need to find out when this container changes it's tiles array.

So something like

```
 Deps.autorun(function() {
    updateContainer(Containers.findOne({_id: containerId}));
 });
```

But I want that container template to be highly reusable. So whatever solution there it should not require some preparations with dependencies.

Where do declare I run that autorun function? (surely i cannot do that in that helper, right?)

Is this the right approach?

Does anybody have better ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually approach this problem is by creating an auxiliary `Collection` object and populate it with a help of appropriate `observer`. In your case this might be something like:

```
// this one should be "global"
var tiles = new Meteor.Collection(null); // empty name
```

Now, depending on the current container, you can populate the `tiles` collection with corresponding data. Also, you'll probably need to remember each object's index:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {

    var containerId = ... // get it somehow, e.g. from Session dictionary
    var tilesIDs = Containers.findOne({_id:containerId}).tiles;

    tiles.remove({}); // this will be performed any time
                      // the current container changes

    Tiles.find({ _id : { $in : tilesIDs } }).observeChanges({
        added: function (id, fields) {
            tiles.insert(_.extend({
                _index : _.indexOf(tilesIDs, id),
                _id    : id,
            }, fields);
        },
        changed: ... // you'll also need to implement
        removed: ... // these to guys
    });

});
```

The helper code is now really simple:

```
Template.container.tiles = function () {
    return tiles.find({}, {sort : {_index : 1}});
}
```

**EDIT:**

Please note, that in order to prevent the whole list being rerendered every time the container object changes (e.g. the order of tiles changes), you'll need to make a separate `listOfTiles` template that does not depend on the container object itself.

Comment: This looks very good. But since i may display many containers on one page, I could perhaps somehow wrap this into a transform function of the Containers collection?

Comment: Good point! But I would rather use `transform` function for `Tiles` collection. Note that the main task here is to find out what is the `index` of a particular tile in it's parent `tiles` list.

Comment: Also, you can generalize the above solution (but I think that a proper use of transform function may be a better idea). I that case you'll also need to set fields like `_parent` (for tiles copies in the auxiliary collection) and handle the observer callbacks more carefully.

Comment: @d_inevitable Here is an example implementation of what I'm talking about: [apendua/meteor-relations](https://github.com/apendua/meteor-relations). I hope this will be usefull.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot!! I only got as far as preventing to the container to invalidate when a tile changes, but not when the order changes or when the new tiles are added. Will check out your version tomorrow.