# How do I get templates inserted from custom block helpers to be individually rerendered in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

When I use the built-in block helper `#each`, `book` templates are rerendered individually when changed:

```
users = 
  _id: 'foo'
  books: [
    {name: 'book1'}
    {name: 'book2'}
  ]
```

```
<template name="user">
  {{#each books}}
    {{> book}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="book">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
</template>
```

When the data is changed - the first book name is set to `'bookone'` instead of `'book1'` - only the `book` template (the div containing `'book1'`) is rerendered. This is the desired behavior. When I use a custom block helper, the behavior is different:

```
<template name="user">
  {{#each_with_id}}
    {{> book}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="book">
  <div data-id="{{_id}}">{{name}}</div>
</template>
```

```
Templates.user.each_with_id = (options) ->
  html = "
  for book, i in this.books
    this.name = book.name
    html += Spark.labelBranch i.toString(), ->
      options.fn this
  html
```

Now when the name of the first book changes, the whole `user` template is rerendered.

Comment: Not an answer because not tested, but you might be able to solve this by wrapping the inside of the for loop in a Deps.autorun(). It is very useful for separating out reactive code blocks.

Comment: What happens if you replace your `each_with_id` function with a version that doesn't mention Spark? See an alternative at http://rockycode.com/blog/handlebars-loop-index/ (in your case, change `{ i: i, iPlus1: i + 1 }` to just `{ i: i }`)

Comment: Christian, wrapping all or part of the loop body in an autorun does not work. Geoffrey, the label is needed in order for the live updates to occur (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/281#issuecomment-13162687)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work as you expect, because the implementation of built-in `each` is based on the `cursor.observeChanges` feature. You will not be able to achieve the same exact result without using an auxiliary collection of some sort. The idea is quite simple. It seems that you don't have a "books" collection but you can create a client-side-only cache:

```
Books = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

where you will need to put some data dynamically like this:

```
Users.find({/* probably some filtering here */}).observeCanges({
  added: function (id, fields) {
    _.each(fields.books, function (book, index) {
      Books.insert(_.extend(book, {
        owner: id,
        index: index,
      }));
    }
  },
  changed: function (id, fields) {
    Books.remove({
      owner:id, name:{
        $nin:_.pluck(fields.books, 'name')
      },
    });
    _.each(fields.books, function (book, index) {
      Books.update({
        owner : id,
        name  : book.name,
      }, {$set:_.extend(book, {
        owner : id,
        index : index,
      })}, {upsert:true});
    }
  },
  removed: function (id) {
    Books.remove({owner:id});
  },
});
```

Then instead of `each_with_id` you will be able to the built-in `each` with appropriate  cursor, e.g.

```
Books.find({owner:Session.get('currentUserId')}, {sort:{index:1}});
```

You may also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455443/isolate-reactivity-in-an-ordered-list/19458156#19458156) other topic which basically covers the same problem you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work. Do you think there might be a way that doesn't involve a new collection? By manual setting Deps/observing the right things - doing the equivalent of what is done inside #each?

Comment: Yes, there is another solution. That would require writing a custom publish method and feed your existing collection with some additional meta-data. But this is so far away from your original question, that I think it would be better to post another one if you want to discuss it further.